# Ansible tower to AWX migration - inventories, templates, hosts

Tags: python-3.x, api, ansible, ansible-awx

I am working on a migration task ie migrate from ansible tower to awx. My focus is to export inventories, hosts projects and job templates. What I did to get started is to use a python script to export all inventories etc to json file. Sample code to fetch all inventories from all pages and save it to json file is as follows:

```
inventoryReponse = []
r = requests.get('{}/api/v2/inventories/'.format(args.url), auth=HTTPBasicAuth(args.username, args.password)).json()
inventoryReponse.extend(r['results'])
next_page = r['next']

while next_page != None:
    res = requests.get('{}{}'.format(args.url, next_page), auth=HTTPBasicAuth(args.username, args.password)).json()
    inventoryReponse.extend(res['results'])
    # print(next_page, res)
    next_page = res['next']

filepath = '/Users/username/AWX/exported_inventories.json'
with open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(inventoryReponse, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

In the same way I export hosts, projects and job_templates from my ansible tower. Now I am stuck on how to migrate/import this json data to my AWX. Am I on correct path or is there any other way to migrate inventories etc from Ansible tower to AWX? Any other information on ansible tower to AWX migration will be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't use the [awx command line interface](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/index.html) to perform these exports / imports? You can directly check the [dedicated examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/examples.html#import-export)

Comment: Since i am very much new on ansible/awx side and more of a python developer i was looking into that side.I will look into these examples, thanks. It will be great help if you could give give me an exmple of exporting inventories to json file.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towercli/usage.html#resources-and-actions

Answer (score -1):

If I get it right, you should have the json file of the exported data.
You can further use the "awx import" command to import the data to AWX.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).